# VBA User Defined Function to combine 2 functions to simplify nested formula (Custom Function with vlookup)

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, vlookup

I am trying to create an UDF to simplify nested formula.
Please refer image below:

[image]

Here I have a reference data in cells D9:E16.

I have to update name of the club in column B with respect to Player Name in Column A.
Right now I have a custom function "SearchChars" which does a Fuzzy Lookup. From this output I am applying a vlookup on reference table to fetch the Name of the football club. This reference table always has 2 Columns only i.e. Player Name and Club Name.
I want to create an UDF for this which will look like below:

=PlayerClub(Player_Name,Player_List,Club_Name)

My code is as below which is giving me a #VALUE! error (Please refer last 3 lines of the Code):

```
Function SearchChars(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant

For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = cell
  For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
    If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
      a = a + 1
      cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
  Next i

a = a - Len(cell)
  
If a > b Then
  b = a
  Value = str
End If

a = 0
Next cell
SearchChars = Value
End Function

Function Player_Club(lookup_value As String, tbl_array1 As Range, tbl_array2 As Range) As String

Player_Club = VLookup(SearchChars(lookup_value, tbl_array1), tbl_array2)

End Function
```

Request help to find the solution

Comment: Well first of all it would be `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` or maybe `Application.Vlookup`.

Comment: And that function requires 3 criteria with a 4th as optional.  You are only passing 2.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for revert. Tried the suggested. getting Compile Error: Argument not Optional

Comment: `Player_Club = Application.VLookup(SearchChars(lookup_value, tbl_array1), tbl_array2, 2, False)`

Comment: @Scott Craner Hats off to you!!! This works..Thanks a ton.